# setOnkeypress event in popup box javafx

Tags: javafx, modal-dialog, popupwindow

Can I get key pressed event `setOnKeyPress` on a popup?

My parent root is opening one popup box and this popup box contains "ok" button. 
I want to generate an event on pressing the enter key on keyboard and it should "submit" (trigger "ok" button of) that popup dialog box.

I have used the following code:

```
NicheSuitePOSController.getApplication().getScene().getRoot().getScene().getRoot().getScene()
            .setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$   131  enter pressed" + ke.getCode());
                    if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$   133  enter pressed");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by `submit that popup` ?

Comment: popup has a button ok that has some event to be triggered

Comment: You can attach the `Key Press` event on the scene of the Pop-Up. If that is what you want..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
[Button.defaultButtonProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#defaultButtonProperty()) without attaching any key event handlers to the scene or dialogbox.